# Array.prototype.sort() not changing order when returning positive value?

Tags: javascript

I'm having a little trouble understanding the basic `sort()` function.

All I want to do is to move all 0s of an array to the end of the array **without changing the order of the other elements**. In the docs I've read 100x that:

> If compareFunction(a, b) returns greater than 0, sort b to an index
> lower than a (i.e. b comes first).

**Now I'm doing:**

```
function moveZeros(arr) {
    return arr.sort((a, b) => a === 0 ? 1 : 0)
}

const input = [1,2,0,1,0,1,0,3,0,1]

document.write(moveZeros(input));
```

But the order is not changing. Putting the zeros to the front of the array with -1 works but moving them forward does not seem to work and I can't seem to figure out why. What am I missing?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Your answer changes the order of elements in the rest of the array. I wanted the rest of the elements to be unaffected which I thought 0 would do.

Comment: if you want to do that instead, the question is not descriptive enough, but at that point you can filter non zero and append zeros after.

Comment: Instead of using `sort`, you could simply loop through the array and put all the zeros and non-zeros in 2 separate arrays and concat them afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use both values for sorting.

This approach take the the difference of the boolean negated values.

In this case zero is becoming `true` and the all zero values are moved to right side.

```
[
    all truthy values, like numbers not zero
    all falsy values, like zero
]
```

```js
function moveZeros(arr) {
    return arr.sort((a, b) => !a - !b);
}

console.log(moveZeros([1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1]));
```

Comment: This is very elegant. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You do not consider that the parameter `b` can also be 0

```js
function moveZeros(arr) {
    return arr.sort((a, b) => a === 0 ? 1 : (b === 0 ? -1 : 0));
}

const input = [1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 1];

console.log(moveZeros(input));
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your input, but I still don't get it. Even if you give `[1, 0, 2]` as the input to my function (no chance that there will be two elements with a value of 0). Why doesn't it work? returning a positive number should place `a` to a higher index than `b`?

Comment: maybe this will help you figure it out: `return arr.sort((a, b) => { console.log(a,b); return a === 0 ? 1 : 0 })`

Comment: Ok, tried that before but know looked a little deeper into it and your write. I think I have a better grasp of this now.

Comment: @Xen_mar If you are interested in exactly the algorithm used for sorting, then _As ECMAScript doesn’t specify any sorting algorithm to be implemented by Array.sort(), it totally depends on browser which sorting algorithm to be implement._ so you cannot rely on a specific algorithm and must consider both parameters